# 4 MHz RF-receiver not working

Tags: pcb, rf, high-frequency, resonance, receiver

I have been trying to make a 4 MHz receiver, to receive a ASK/OOK modulated signal but it never really works. I have my suspicions that it's the LC tank that is not tuned correctly, I am quite new to electronics as you probably will see when analysing the circuit.

The circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Notes: The tank circuit consists of: L1, C1 and to some degree C2 as it is in series with C1.

The amplification stage is working in regards of amplifying all signals from the antenna (Vin), but the attenuation above and below 4 MHz is not visible. I did a Fourier transform using my oscilloscope, but I could not see any specific amplification around 4 MHz.
To make matters worse, the circuit starts oscillating at 180-230 kHz sometimes which I suspect comes from the Q2 feedback.

R1 determines is the bandwidth of the LC tank resonance, and I have tried with different values.

Finally, here is a simulation of the circuit in LTspice. Vin is supplied with an AC sweeping signal from 1 Hz to 5 MHz:

[image: Magnitude and Phase]

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: I have implemented the circuit on a perfboard:
[image]

Comment: So it works in theory, but not in the physical implementation. But you have told us nothing at all about your physical implementation. Show us some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that an input signal *voltage source*, substitutes for an antenna signal...

The signal source impedance of a voltage source is very low, whereas the tank resonator of L1, C1 requires a higher impedance at 4 MHz if you intend to see a resonant voltage peak. Furthermore, tank resonance occurs at 7 MHz, not 4 MHz. Replacing C1 of 200pf with 620pf gets you closer to a resonance peak 4 MHz.

> [,,,]To make matters worse, the circuit starts oscillating at 180-230 kHz
> sometimes which I suspect comes from the Q2 feedback.

Yes, that's likely. Try increasing value of C2 greatly. As you increase C2, instability moves down in frequency, but 10uf might suppress instability enough.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser! C1 used to be around 620p which in theory shall give a resonance frequency at around 4 MHz, but during the simulation it gave something like 500 kHz which i thought was strange.